# Check for uninitialized non optional value in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, string, null, option-type

I have some code that has been working fine for a long time but suddenly is causing a crash ar runtime. It may be because this is the first time that it got a nil value (due to some glitch or whatever) but in any case my app is now crashing at launch.

The code is:

```
 @objc func download(surl: NSString, completion : @escaping (NSData) -> Void ) {
print("surl to download is:",surl)//CRASHES HERE if surl is uninitialized.
```

It crashes on the line indicated with error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

Here is a screenshot of the console where the error occurs at runtime[image]:

Here is the line in the debugger where it says it is "unitiailized" at time of crash.

[image]
Is there anyway to check for uninitialized if surl is non optional?

I am reluctant to change surl to an optional because this method is called umpteen places in the app and I'm afraid that changing it in the method will cause something else to break.

So would like to figure out a way to test if surl is uninitialized and return if that is possible.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Edit:

I have tried a test of not nil in the method that calls the above method and  passes the not nil test. But it then crashes if you try to do something with it. Also, printing it in the console after the crash gives: `(NSString) $R2 = <uninitialized>`

Here is screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your code is crashing there? why are you using NSString/NSData at first place?

Comment: With your implementation `surl` cannot be `nil`. The compiler would complain (at compile time) if it was. That's the benefit of the Swift strong type system. The error must be somewhere else. And as Leo already mentioned stop using `NS...` classes if there is a native Swift counterpart.

Comment: @Leo Dabus it looks like the code is crashing there.  See screenshot. Using NSString because this is mainly an Objective-C project. However, a few functions such as this one are written in Swift

Comment: @vadian. Rechecking the console, it says "uninitialized". As mentioned this code has worked in a production app for over a year, but somehow an invalid value has crept in.  Not sure how. Could have been a crash or something. Will edit the question to how can I check for uninitialized. At the end of the day, I need to test for unitialized values even if they are very rare as the error prevents app from working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be your Swift code is called from Objective-C, and Objective-C sends nil to Swift. This would explain why you get the crash at the end of the chain, only where the value is actually used.

Note that Objective-C will happily pass a nil value to a Swift function that doesn't accept nil, and also Swift will happily forward<sup>1</sup> that nil value to places where only non-nils are allowed, crashing only where it actually tries to use the value.

And from what I can see in your stacktrace, this seems to be the problem: the Objective-C `-[IDModel updateCa..]` method calls the `Utilities.downloadImag...` Swift method, which forwards the call to `Utilities.download(surl..`, and the crash happens on the last function in the chain, when the value is attempted to be used.

What you can do in order to have a minimal impact of the changes, is to "overload" the function, one with an optional `surl` for the Objective-C world, and one for the Swift world:

```swift
@objc(download) func objcDownload(surl: NSString?, completion : @escaping (NSData) -> Void ) {
    guard let surl = surl else {
        // handle this problems
        return
    }
    // forward to the worker function
    download(surl: surl, completion: completion)
}

// @nonobjc might not be needed, depending of the class declaration
// but being explicit doesn't hurt
@nonobjc func download(surl: NSString, completion : @escaping (NSData) -> Void ) {
    // same code, no changes needed
}
```

This way:

- Objective-C code will see the same function, no changes needed
- The Swift implementation of the Objective-C bridge can check for nils
- The Swift code can still use the, now `@nonobjc` download function.

---

If you don't trust me about the nil values passed from Objective-C to Swift, here's an example to prove it:

```objectivec
// in a header file, imported in the bridging header
@interface ObjCWorker: NSObject

+ (void)sendNilToSwift;

@end

// in the corresponding .m file
@implementation ObjCWorker

+ (void)sendNilToSwift {
    NSString *shouldNotBeNil = nil;
    [SwiftWorker doWorkWithNonNull:shouldNotBeNil];
}
@end
```

```swift
// in a Swift file
class SwiftWorker: NSObject {
    
    @objc static func doWork(with string: NSString) {
        delegateWorkToSomeOtherMethod(string)
    }
    
    static func delegateWorkToSomeOtherMethod(_ string: NSString) {
        delegateWorkToAnotherMethod(string)
    }
    
    static func delegateWorkToAnotherMethod(_ string: NSString) {
        print(string)
    }
}
```

Now, just write `ObjCWorker.sendNilToSwift()`, and you'll the exact same crash in action.

<sup>1</sup>Note that this currently works only for Objective-C params: NSString, NSData, ..., bridged Swift types like String, Data somehow get initialized with an empty value when they are send as nil values from the Objective-C side.

Comment: But isn't it just wrong for the OP to be giving these parameters Objective-C types in the first place? NSString and NSData are just wrong.

Comment: @matt agreed, feels wrong to use NSString, when String work work as well (or maybe even better). Maybe the OP inherited this codebase and doesn't want to touch it too much.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent explanation, You are right that the method is failing when called from Obj-C methods. The reason for NSString and NSData is the Objective-C methods send it a string (NSString in the calling methods and then use the NSData that is returned. Within the function (code not shown) it does use string and data.